# Flutter Hooks. Where to "requestPermission" as it doesn't have an initState

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I am learning Flutter Hooks, but I can't find anything about what to use when you need to have a specific permission request which usually goes in the initState, for example:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissions();
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
    _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
  }

  void _requestPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }...
```

Now migrating this to use hooks the initState and dispose are not "needed" as it handles that for you which is nice in many situations, but I can't wrap my head around where to place this type of request permissions for example?

How to request those permissions when using `class HomePage extends HookWidget`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is by using a `StatefulHookWidget` instead of a `HookWidget`. `StatefulHookWidget` behaves just as the `StatefulWidget` but you can use hooks inside of the build method.